# Access a teacher's courses

Tags: google-classroom

Currently, to access a particular teacher's courses on Android, we -

1. Get all the courses for the user.
2. Get all the teachers for each of those courses.
3. For each of the teachers for each of the courses, check if our user is a teacher for any of them.

Is there a simpler way of just filtering the courses for the user to only those for which they are a teacher?

It seems I can set parameters according to the API documentation - https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list

But, how do I do that via java. The list() method on courses does not take any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... needed to use setTeacherId() function on the list() function.

```
  ListCoursesResponse coursesResponse = mActivity.mService.courses().list()
            .setTeacherId(user.getId())
            .setPageSize(1)
            .execute();
```